# Listeners installation

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

I am creating a PowerShell script that automates the Oracle software install. Right now everything is working correctly until I trying and setup the two listeners for  the software.

When manually installing the database software you have to open a new shell and execute these two commands after the software has been installed....

```
netca -silent -responsefile c:\path\to\netca_listener.rsp
netca -silent -responsefile c:\path\to\netca_callout_listener.rsp
```

I have been trying to execute these two rsp files like so..

```
saps -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c", "netca", "-silent", "-responsefile $first_rspfile" -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait
```

Typically the process will spin briefly, but then will do nothing, and the response files will pop open when the process starts running.

Any clues to what might be going on?

Comment: Does the path `$first_rspfile` contains spaces?.....perhaps you need to wrap that in single quotes: `"-responsefile '$first_rspfile'"`

Comment: No, $first_rspfile does not contain spaces.  I've tried sing quotes, but have no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `cmd /c` in PowerShell. Try this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "netca.exe" `
    -ArgumentList @("-silent", "-responsefile $first_rspfile") `
    -WindowStyle "Hidden" -Wait
```

Comment: I am receiving this error now... `Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At c:\path\to\modle.psm1:16 char:9
+     saps <<<<  -FilePath "netca" -ArgumentList "-silent", "-responsefile $first_rspfile" -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand `

Comment: Well, where's `netca.exe`? If it's not in the same folder where your script is and not in a folder that is on `%path%`, you need to specify full path (e.g. `C:\folder\netca.exe`).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to get the full path to the `.exe` to be able to execute the process.  When manually trying to run the command I would typically just open a new shell and run the command, but when running it as a process I had to map the pathway.  Thanks again!